# How C2 compiler in hotspot jvm translate memory barriers to assmebly code

Tags: java, x86, jit, jvm-hotspot, memory-barriers

I am trying to understand how c2 compiler in hotspot jvm translate memory barriers for load/store of volatile variables to assembly code.

I understand that for x86 to add StoreLoad barrier, the interpreter will add `lock; addl $0,0(%%esp)` to the assembly code. So what about c2 compiler? I know c2 operates on Ideal Graph (IR), and adds appropriate barrier nodes before and after load/store nodes (for volatile variables). Do they use `lock` as in the interpreter mode, or use fence instructions (`LFENCE`, `SFENCE` and `MFENCE`)? Is the code for barriers emitted in compiler mode the same with interpreter mode? Can I refer to some translation rules or manually check them?

Comment: lfence and sfence are useless (except for sfence after NT stores), and `lock addl $0, (%esp)` is just another way to do what `mfence` does (more efficiently on some CPUs) [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40409297).  But ESP instead of RSP?  Do you care about 32-bit code?  And yes, you can check HotSpot's final optimized asm: [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503479).

Comment: You might find something about where in the HotSpot sources to look for how it JITs in [Where is the assembly implementation code of the intrinsic method in Java HotSpot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48198982) - that's about JITing a specific intrinsic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm)  (edit: bleh, not used to *not* having a gold badge in any of the tags of a question like this; I only added x86 myself so it doesn't count for duphammering)

Comment: [Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27627969) explains why LFENCE and SFENCE are irrelevant; unless you're using NT stores, regular loads/stores already have ordering that strong.  And you can't combine them to build an MFENCE full barrier.  [Does the Intel Memory Model make SFENCE and LFENCE redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32705169)

Comment: Thanks! I understood that the compiler uses `lock` instead of `MFENCE` for memory barriers. I have checked the assembly code dumped by PrintAssembly flag and found the lock instructions.

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question if you want.  Feel free to summarize or copy my comments and/or links if you want.